How to show border with double line and alpha color in JavaFX WebView / WebKit?
I need a border with double line and alpha color in WebView. This is my code:
public class WebViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        String htmlContent = """
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <style>
                        .styled-span {
                            color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
                            border-bottom-style: double;
                            border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
                            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                            font-weight: normal;
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>
                        This is a <span class="styled-span">styled span</span> example in JavaFX WebView.
                    </p>
                </body>
                </html>
                """;

        webView.getEngine().loadContent(htmlContent);

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

And this is the result:

If I use border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1); I get

Could anyone say how to do it, if it is possible?
PS. webView.getEngine().getUserAgent() returns this version: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/617.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/23 Safari/617.1.

did you try the hexa value notation #ff000066; ?

@MisterJojo I tried - it doesn't work. As I understand web engine converts #ff000066; to rgba(...).

Why border? Doesn't text-decoration: underline double work?

@Kosh I can't use text-decoration: underline double because I already use text-decoration-line: line-through. In some cases I need double underline + line through

You might use <u> and <s> elements instead of just one <span>. See also <del> and <ins> if aplicable.

A curious bug.  The border styles dotted, dashed, and solid work properly;  the styles double, groove, ridge, inset, and outset all have the issue described here.

Do you have the freedom to modify the HTML content?  I believe a workaround is possible by having a span inside a span, and applying a single solid border to each of them.

@VGR Thank you very much for your suggestion. I need this for a project where content and styles are generated dynamically for different platforms. So, I can modify styles, but not content. In content I have <span> and I can add any styles to it.

A curious bug.  The border styles dotted, dashed, and solid work properly;  the styles double, groove, ridge, inset, and outset all have the issue described here.
I was able to adapt https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/ into a workable solution:
public class WebViewTranslucencyTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        String htmlContent = """
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <style>
                        .styled-span {
                            position: relative;
                            color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
                            border-bottom-style: solid;
                            border-bottom-width: 1px;
                            border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
                            font-weight: normal;
                            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                        }
                        .styled-span:before {
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index: -1;
                            content: " ";
                            left: 0;
                            right: 0;
                            top: 0;
                            bottom: -3px;
                            border-bottom-style: solid;
                            border-bottom-width: 1px;
                            border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>
                        This is a <span class="styled-span">styled span</span> example in JavaFX WebView.
                    </p>
                </body>
                </html>
                """;

        webView.getEngine().loadContent(htmlContent);

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

